# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'superset.cli.main'; 'superset.cli' is not a package

Tags: python, docker-compose, apache-superset

I am trying to install apache/superset version 1.3.2 using docker compose on mac os. but it fails with below error.
looks like superset_init container is failing while applying db migration.
i did not find any issue similar to this on the internet.

Error:
Init Step 1/4 [Starting] -- Applying DB migrations

######################################################################

Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/app/docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py]

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/superset", line 33, in

```
sys.exit(load_entry_point('apache-superset', 'console_scripts', 'superset')())
```

File "/usr/local/bin/superset", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point

```
return next(matches).load()
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load

```
module = import_module(match.group('module'))
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module

```
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
```

File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import

File "", line 991, in _find_and_load

File "", line 970, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'superset.cli.main'; 'superset.cli' is not a package

From the error looks like it is looking for 'superset.cli.main'; 'superset.cli' packages but in superset version 1.3.2 has only cli.py module under superset folder.

Please help me understand why it is happening. let me know if anything else is needed

Answer (score 0):

This error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'superset.cli.main'; 'superset.cli' is not a package` may also occur if you have file has the name `superset.cli` (or something like that) in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

In this case, rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module.